# Google Maps V2 - Android - invalidate() Equivalent

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to write a method that is equivalent to the following code:

```
private MapView mGoogleMapView; 

public void clearAnimation() { 
    if (mGoogleMapView != null) { 
        mGoogleMapView.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

that will work with Google Map V2 for Android.  How can I accomplish this using the Google Maps V2 API for Android?

Comment: Why were you doing this in the first place? IOW, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here is the shot:

```
GoogleMap map;
.....
map.stopAnimation();
```

This will stop camera animation which is in progress right now